# Launching apps programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nsworkspace

I have been playing around with NSWorkspace.

- `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Photos"]` works
- `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Contacts"]` does **not** work
- `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/Contacts.app"]` works

(Mac OS Sierra)

So, I was wondering if there is any safe way to find the "real" application path. Maybe the Contacts app has different names in different localization of the System ? Why is just "Photos" working fine ?

I would imagine that there should be a way, from an Apple documented application identifier to get the application path, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `launchApplication:` returns a `BOOL` if it succeeded or not.

To be really certain of the app you are launching, you can also try looking it up via NSWorkspace's [`URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1534053-urlforapplicationwithbundleident?language=objc) API, into which you can plug Contact's application ID of `com.apple.AddressBook`.

With the result, you can call the explicit location of the app via:

[`- (NSRunningApplication *)launchApplicationAtURL:(NSURL *)url 
                                         options:(NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions)options 
                                   configuration:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)configuration 
                                           error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1534810-launchapplicationaturl?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I was looking for. But how can you be sure of the bundle Identifier - or even be sure it will remain constant in time. I don't find the list in APple's doc (though you can find lists on the Internet).

Comment: Application identifiers don't typically change, unless there is a drastic change (eg iPhoto got replaced with Photos.app)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. In such a case, code using the bundle identifier would be broken. Another solution could be to use openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"photos://"]. Not sure this is more stable in time, but I would tend to say both iPhoto and Photos would both support that URL scheme... I'll accept your answer if nothing better comes in the next day.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to open an app is from file url path. I have did the same for my application like below:

```
NSString *appPathIs = Url.path;
```

I take url path in one string and then open it with as you have indicated

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appPathIs];
```

I have tried every way to achieve the same but sometime they work and sometime not. If you want to try another one then please consider this:

```
NSString *appPathIs = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication:appName];
NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:appPathIs] bundleIdentifier];
NSString *path = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:identifier];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appPathIs];
```